# Difference between mousedown and click

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, editor

I'm trying to create a custom editor from scratch. To move the cursor I have a system with a `click` handler that would move the cursor and then focus my `<input>` element. But I am currently implementing the selection system and to do that I had to change my `click` event handler to a `mousedown` event. But for some unknown reason, when I click somewhere the focus does not work.

The click handler, If you change "mousedown" to "click" everything works

```
document.querySelector(".tab-editor").addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    var rect = document.querySelector("#line-1").getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.x - rect.x; var y = e.y - rect.y;
    const line = Math.ceil(y / 20);
    writer.moveCursorTo(x, line);
}
```

writer.moveCursorTo()

```
if (line > this.lines.length){line = this.lines.length;}
if (line < 1) {line = 1;}
this.lines[this.currentline - 1].setCurrent(false);
this.currentline = line;
this.lines[this.currentline - 1].setCurrent(true);
cursor.setPos(cursor.x, line * 20 - 20) // set y pos
cursor.moveApproxX(x, this.lines[this.currentline - 1].text()); // set x pos
```

and finally the cursor.setPos

```
this.cursor().style.left = x+"px";
this.cursor().style.top = y+"px";
this.input().style.left = x+"px";
this.input().style.top = y+"px";
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.input().focus();
this.resetBlink();
```

I checked both events, the x and y are the same in the click and mousedown event.
Here is the full code: https://codepen.io/I-Hate-Login/pen/GRwaeBZ

## **-- EDIT --**

To make it clearer:

- This code works
  `document.querySelector(".tab-editor").addEventListener("click", e=>document.querySelector('.editor-input').focus())`
- This code does **not** work
  `document.querySelector(".tab-editor").addEventListener("mousedown", e=>document.querySelector('.editor-input').focus())`

Comment: Litterally, if I use `click` it works if I change to `mousedown` it does not work anymore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

Basically, you need to call the `.preventDefault()` method of the event like so:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", e=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    otherElement.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it works but only when the mouse button is pressed down and the cursor is on .tab-editor-cursor,
I recommend changing mousedown to onmousedown and setting a wider reach where you want to write

Comment: .tab-editor-cursor is the cursor, so what do you mean?

Comment: if you click and hold down the mouse button and at the same time you start typing, your code will work correctly as you have written. the event is triggered only when the mouse button is pressed, that's the idea of onmousedown